# Problem with deploying Next.js application to Netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify

i cant seem to get this to work when i try to deploy. I get this in the building log

" How do i fix this " 8:40:55 PM: $ npm run build
8:40:55 PM: > JT-porto@0.1.0 build
8:40:55 PM: > next build
8:40:55 PM: warn  - No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
8:40:55 PM: info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
8:40:58 PM: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
8:41:00 PM: Failed to compile.
8:41:00 PM:
8:41:00 PM: ./pages/index.js
8:41:00 PM: Module not found: Can't resolve '../public/figma1.png'
8:41:00 PM: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
8:41:00 PM: > Build failed because of webpack errors
8:41:00 PM: ​
8:41:00 PM:   "build.command" failed
8:41:00 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:41:00 PM: ​
8:41:00 PM:   Error message
8:41:00 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
8:41:00 PM: ​
8:41:00 PM:   Error location
8:41:00 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
8:41:00 PM:   npm run build
8:41:00 PM: ​
8:41:00 PM:   Resolved config
8:41:00 PM:   build:
8:41:00 PM:     command: npm run build
8:41:00 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
8:41:00 PM:     environment:
8:41:00 PM:       - NEXT_PRIVATE_TARGET
8:41:00 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/.next
8:41:00 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
8:41:00 PM:   plugins:
8:41:00 PM:     - inputs: {}
8:41:00 PM:       origin: ui
8:41:00 PM:       package: '@netlify/plugin-nextjs'
8:41:00 PM: Caching artifacts
8:41:00 PM: Started saving node modules
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving node modules
8:41:00 PM: Started saving build plugins
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving build plugins
8:41:00 PM: Started saving corepack cache
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving corepack cache
8:41:00 PM: Started saving pip cache
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving pip cache
8:41:00 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
8:41:02 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
8:41:00 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
8:41:00 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
8:41:00 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
8:41:00 PM: Started saving go dependencies
8:41:00 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
8:41:02 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
8:41:02 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
8:41:02 PM: Finished processing build request in 39.698s""

Seems like the PNG is in the right file path. Also when i try to npm run build. I dont get the build folder for manual deployment.

Here is the github https://github.com/joakimtin/reactporto

Comment: Looks like you are trying to import an image using the wrong path. make sure `../public/figma1.png` is a valid relative path and that the image exists

Comment: Hey, but the pictures are showing on the page locally, could it still be wrong? I am confused.

Comment: Your github repo isn't public or the link is incorrect. It's sending me to a 404. I can take a look and give a better answer if you make it public or add some code on your q. Quick note on your post -- when adding logs or code use the code formatting in your post so it's easier to read.

Comment: Noted! Yes im so sorry it was Private. Take a look again if you will i made it puclic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a file naming issue. Inside the public directory change the file extension to `.png` and not `.PNG`